# Regex C - missing match?

Tags: c, regex

I have a problem with a simple regex in C, my last match isn't recognized.

Here is my code :

```
#include <regex.h>
int dummy(const char *s) {
    size_t nmatch = 0, i;
    regex_t preg;
    regmatch_t  *pmatch = NULL;
    char str_regex[255 + 1];

    /* Format : ID <ID> L {<Label>} R <Res> C {Info} T {More info} */
    /* "C" and "T" aren't required */
    snprintf(str_regex, 255,
                    "ID ([[:alnum:]]{1,%d}) L \\{([^}]{1,%d})\\} R ([01])( C \\{[^}]+\\})?( T \\{[^}]+\\})?$",
                    25, // Max 25 chars for id
                    100); // Max 100 chars for label


    if (regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error initialization\n");
            return 2;
    }
    // We got the number of matches
    nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
    pmatch = malloc (sizeof (*pmatch) * nmatch);
    // EDIT : problem solved with pmatch = malloc(size of(*pmatch) * (nmatch + 1));
    if (pmatch == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Memory error\n");
            return 4;
    }

    // String can't be found
    // EDIT : problem solved with : if (regexec(&preg, s, nmatch + 1, pmatch, 0) != 0) {
    if (regexec(&preg, s, nmatch, pmatch, 0) != 0) {
            regfree(&preg);
            free(pmatch); pmatch = NULL;
            fprintf(stderr, "String not valid\n");
            return 5;
    }
    regfree (&preg);

    // EDIT : problem solved with : for (i = 0; i < nmatch + 1; ++i) {
    for (i = 0; i < nmatch; ++i) {
            char tmp[1000]; // Just for test, 1000 char not necessary
            int start = pmatch[i].rm_so;
            int finish = pmatch[i].rm_eo;
            memset(tmp, 0, sizeof(tmp));
            strncpy(tmp, s + start, finish - start);
            printf("Match %d : <%s>\n", i, tmp);
    }
}
```

With an entry string like : `ID ID1 L {Label} R 1 C {Info1} T {Info2}`
I expect to have 5 match

- Complete chain, it's OK
- `<ID1>`, it's OK
- `<Label>`, it's OK
- `<1>`, it's OK
- `<C {Info1}>`, it's OK
- `<T {Info2}>`, it doesn't work

Any idea why the last match doesn't work ?
If I use a chain without or with the last part `(T {Info2})`, it works the same. The "T" part is never recognized...

EDIT : problem solved with "nmatch + 1" instead of nmatch, see in the code above the "EDIT" parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man 3 regex`, `re_nsub` contains the number of subexpressions within the RE. Since you're capturing the complete string as well, don't you need to `malloc(sizeof(*pmatch) * (nmatch + 1))`?

Comment: I guess that re_nsub does count the complete string itself. Always saw a size of nmatch, and I just tried with nmatch + 1 : segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found with the help of nemetroid with `man 3 regex` : you DO have to allocate memory for `nmatch + 1 match`, then pass `nmatch + 1` instead of `nmatch` to `regexec()`, and it does work. Manpage on my server didn't tell me that... Grr. Thanks for the help !